# Configure YOLOv3 to detect few objects of certrain classes

Tags: yolo

I'm new to yolo and currently using YOLOv3. I don't have a expensive GPU and like to test with YOLOv3 to detect only vehicles (8 classes). Is there a way I can do this **without re-training** the model by changing some configs? I'm using the weights file YOLOv3-608.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the classes that you want to detect are not a part of the original mscoco labels listed [here](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/master/cfg/coco.names), I really don't see any way to detect them without re-training/finetuning YOLOv3 on your dataset which has these classes.

For training, you can use google colab which provides you with free GPU access for a limited time (12 hrs per active session)